# How to hook a rope?

Tags: animation, physics, bezier-curves, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

[image]

I'm trying to attach some tin cans to a car to create a concept of "just married". I'm confused to apply physic on it. When turning on "soft body" for rope (curve). Hooks I set are not working. And the other problem is the rope get through to tin can.

[You can download the document to see the problem easier](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pq3WISFX3fd1TK_7cRKFynEQUhr3AC4Z/view?usp=sharing%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9w8Xw2JGdTrnMyY-Iv2IzWlFHFeIYYX/view?usp=sharing)